# How do I install OpenSSL on the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to decode a file using the bash command

```bash
openssl enc -d -aes256 -in blah.tar.gz.enc | tar xz
```

I'm running that from bash on Windows 10 using the terminal that comes with Git (I think that's Cygwin and MinTTY?) but it is too slow (and silent) so I wanted to try using the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). However I do not have openssl in my Debian WSL and I cannot get it to build.

Are there simple instructions to install OpenSSL on WSL?

Comment: OpenSSL is also [available for Windows](https://www.cloudinsidr.com/content/how-to-install-the-most-recent-version-of-openssl-on-windows-10-in-64-bit/).

Comment: Run this command: `sudo apt install openssl`

Comment: @Biswapriyo when I run that command I get the following error: `dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/openssl_1.1.0k-1~deb9u1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to install new version of '/usr/share/doc/openssl/README.ECC': Permission denied
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/openssl_1.1.0k-1~deb9u1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: @Biswapriyo please consider posting this comment as an answer